# Gridview SqlDataSource; Problem with update

Tags: asp.net, gridview, .net-2.0

I'm trying to do an update of the form

```
UPDATE TableName 
   SET field1 = NewValue
   WHERE field1 = OldValue
```

but I'm not quite sure how to do it with GridView.

I have this for my Gridview markup

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"  AllowPaging="True" DataKeyNames="cftm_emp_name" PageSize="30">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Image" SelectImageUrl="~/Images/sel.jpg" ShowSelectButton="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="cftm_emp_name" HeaderText="CF Team Member" SortExpression="cftm_emp_name" />
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

and the SqlDataSource looks like this

```
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
            ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [cftm_emp_name] FROM [rpc_extra_cf_team_members] ORDER BY [cftm_emp_name]" OnUpdating="SqlDataSource1_Updating" UpdateCommand="UPDATE rpc_extra_cf_team_members SET cftm_emp_name = ? WHERE cftm_emp_name = ?">
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="cftm_emp_name" Type="String" />
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1" Name="cftm_emp_name" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

EDIT:

No errors but it just does not update it. I set a break point in `OnUpdating` event handler and I noticed that both parameters are set to `OldValue`.

Let me know if there is any additional info required and I would appreciate any help on this.

Thanks

Comment: so, you are trying to update all rows with OldValue for field1 to NewValue ?

Comment: if you want to update all row then this code is valid.

Comment: @TheOtherGuy - Seems ok to me, if you are getting some errors then update your question.

Comment: Not all rows per say, but just the rows with value = OldValue for field1. What I have does not work. It just does not update at all.

Comment: @Bibhu added an edit section with what happens when I try this. Thanks

Comment: yah my meaning is same as u say..\

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you are updating the primary key field named **cftm_emp_name**, which you are using as **DataKeyNames="cftm_emp_name"** in your case. The field of the table that we use as DataKeyNames of GridView acts as primary key of the table. So, in your table, "cftm_emp_name" is the primary key and you cannot update the primary key. Try to update the  other fields of your table by using "cftm_emp_name" field as primary key for the search criteria.

For example, you can use an update query such as:

```
 UpdateCommand="UPDATE rpc_extra_cf_team_members SET cftm_emp_add = @cftm_emp_add WHERE cftm_emp_name = @cftm_emp_name"
```

```
<UpdateParameters>
  <asp:Parameter Name="cftm_emp_add" Type="String" />
  <asp:Parameter Name="cftm_emp_name" Type="String" />   
</UpdateParameters>
```

Answer (score 0):

set the datakeymember property of sqldatasource as your primary key field in the table and try. hope it helps

Comment: why are you using two parameter for the same filed ?

Comment: I have `SET field1 = NewValue
   WHERE field1 = OldValue` so I'm using two params for same field, one for newvalue and one for oldValue.